# What happens to saved data in Core Data on app update

Tags: iphone, ios

the headline just about sums up my question: What happens to previously saved data in Core Data when I ship a new version of my app?
From what I understand, migration only matters for changes in the data model - still I want to be sure before I start building... Would be pretty awkward, if all the data was gone once the customer loads the shiny new version, wouldn't it?
Just to be sure...
Please forgive my ignorance; I couldn't find anything in the docs or the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All data is keet as it is, assuming you do not change the bundle name / Application Identifier.

You can see it on the simulator as it keeps the data just like on the device itself.

Comment: Yup, just realized this by reading another post related to my question...And by remembering what I saw all day long while testing... Thank you for confirming this!

Comment: You are welcome, Assuming this solution worked for you - may I suggest you accept this answer... it will do your profile good for future questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a persistent SQLite store, the new app reload data from the sqlite file.
You have a  persistent SQLite store if you wrote a line like this

```
NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"YourProject.sqlite"];
```